# PHP - local variable changes result in global changes

Tags: php

I am stuck, I can't find any reference to this problem. It shouldn't be happening. The global variable `$assignmentInfo` is passed into the function, manipulated, and returned as a different variable.

BUT, the local manipulations within the function are propagated to the global variable, so that the next time the function gets called, `$assignmentInfo` has been changed. I want to pass in the same, unchanging version of `$assignmentInfo` each time I call the function.

Any suggestions?

```
function studentScores($submissionInfo, $assignmentInfo){
    //********************************** Add submission data to assignment data ****************************************************************************
    foreach($assignmentInfo as $assignmentGroup){
        foreach($assignmentGroup->assignments as $assignment){
            foreach($submissionInfo as $submission){
                if(isset($assignment->id) and isset($submission->assignment_id) and $assignment->id == $submission->assignment_id){
                    if (isset($submission->score)){$assignment->score = $submission->score;}
                    if (isset($submission->submitted_at)){$assignment->submitted_at = $submission->submitted_at;}
                    if (isset($submission->workflow_state)){$assignment->workflow_state = $submission->workflow_state;}
                    break;
                }
            }       
        }
    }
    $studentScores = $assignmentInfo;
    return $studentScores;
}

$studentScores = studentScores($submissionInfo->submissions, $assignmentInfo);
```

Comment: That is what I think, but if I pull out the foreach block and print $assignmentInfo, the variable remains unchanged.

Comment: Do you use any framework or something else? Can this framework (ORM for example) change object state in global space while you make foreach? Because of your code must work correct. You have a bad style, but no error.

Comment: No framework, just a very simple interface. How do you mean bad style, I would like to make it better

Comment: I mean, it's better practice to declare variable `studentScores` first and fill it in your foreach if you intend to return `studentScores`, instead of changing input parameters. Read Macconnel's "Code complete" and "Rapid Application Development" by James Martin